# Copy Image to new Folder Ajax Jscript

Tags: php, ajax, image, jscript

i have an image upload in a message box and i am wanting to copy the image to a new folder from the selected image's source folder on uploading of the image.

At present i have a simple ajax posting the name of the file and i am using the source dir as the display src .

However i have been trying to find a way to copy the image to a new folder for uploads , but i have failed badly for the past few days.

I have scrawled the net looking for an answer but have not managed to find a suitable fix..

Can anybody see from the code below how i could copy the image to a new folder with jscript ... also if there is a way to do this with php but still use the ajax i would also be interested as i update the image/message box on upload without page refreshing..

```
function myScript(){  
 var ext = input.files[0]['name'].substring(input.files[0]['name'].lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();   //passed thisID    --onclick   this

  var newimageurl  = input.files[0].name;

    if (input.files && input.files[0] && (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg"))
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();      
        reader.onload = function (e) {

            $.ajax({

            url:"inserteditNEWIMAGE.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,

                        data:{

                        messageID:messageid,
                        newimageURL:newimageurl,
                        newimageID:newimageid,
                        },
                        async: true,

                            success:function(data){

                            var mylink = "loadimageinputs.php?messageid=" + messageid;
                            $('#addimages'+messageid).load(mylink);

                            '+newimageid+' '+newimageurl+' '+messageid);
                            }
            });
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);



        }
        else {      
        alert('Gif Jpeg Jpg Png Only Please');
        return false;
        }


};
```

P.S

I do pass a source path  ---

```
var imagesrc = $('#' + imageid).attr('src');
```

But how do i use this to copy the image to a new folder..

I also tried the php method of posting but the POST only received the name of the file through ajax.. so i could not acquire the actual image...

Comment: So you insert the image and afterwards you want to copy it to anthoer folder? This should be easily done with a few lines of php code in the script called by your ajax post. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: im only sending a filename to the php by the looks of it, i tried to do tthwe php move_uploaded but the php page couldnt find the file data, as it only receives a text filename.... var newimageurl  = input.files[0].name;  but yes you are correct, im will try sending the file sumhow over to the php file for it, but im unsuew as to how il send the image and data via ajax. as this attempt only seems to send a text filename

Comment: var wholeimage = imagesrc+newimageurl; this gives me the complete image source and dir. so im hoping with this posted to the php i will be able to move_uploaded with the $var...

Comment: Otherwise you might wanna have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/) which shows you on how to post image formdata via ajax.